# ServerSocket fails upons construction

Tags: java, sockets, port

I have the following construction:

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create server socket.");
}
```

and the construction fails and I get the "Could not create server socket" error. The port is always 8085. I opened both out-bounding and in-bounding ports in my (Windows 7) firewall. What could be the problem?

The exception is IOException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create server socket.
>       at cs236369.proxy.ProxyServer.(ProxyServer.java:23)
>       at cs236369.proxy.ProxyServer.main(ProxyServer.java:62)

Running `netstat -an` gives the following result:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8085           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8085              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at cs236369.proxy.ProxyServer.<init>(ProxyServer.java:21)
at cs236369.proxy.ProxyServer.main(ProxyServer.java:63)
```

Comment: what exception is e? could you please get it printed and post it here?

Comment: is the user you logged into windows with an admin user?

Comment: I am logged in as the only user in the system, which is an admin.

Comment: Is 8085 currently being used by any other process? `netstat -an` would help here. And +1 for the results of e.printStackTrace() would help.

Comment: Stack trace would help us immensely.

Comment: Catching an exception to throw an exception sounds like bad practice to me.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy @Vladimir @ach_l @noob :: stack trace has been added.

Comment: After you posted your trace, then it seems my answer and ach_l are correct. Another process is using your port. Change the port =). As for catching an exception to throw another one, I don't think it's bad practice if you plan on floating the exception up the stack and want to limit the type of exceptions handled. This is useful also if you want to hide the implementation from the caller but still wish to convey something bad happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API, a [BindException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html)

> Signals that an error occurred while
>   attempting to bind a socket to a local
>   address and port. Typically, the port
>   is in use, or the requested local
>   address could not be assigned.

Basically, that port could be in use by another process, even perhaps by another instance of the same application due to an unclean shutdown. This [link](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2038003&tstart=0) may help you troubleshoot.

Note:

The posted results of running the `netstat -an` command seems to verify that port 8085 is in use by multiple processes, which would result in the `BindException` that you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a more detailed reason for your exception if you include the caught exception in the newly thrown exception:

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create server socket.", e);
}
```

My initial guess, though, is that the port is already in use if you've already dealt with firewall issues.